# Drawing graph with unknown constant

Tags: tikz-pic

`Q=VC(1-e^\frac{-t}{RC})`
Is it possible to plot this function, Q-t graph? V and C are unknown constants.

Comment: That should be a series of curves (Q-t graph). `V` does not matter here in terms of shape (so you may even normalize the value of `Q` by `VC`). Resistor and capacity values do matter so you may choose a series of parameters and draw them on the same figure. That will show how the charging works with respect to parameters `R` and `C`. (For example, the smaller `R` is, the faster the charging goes).

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thin,color=gray!15,step=1] (0,0) grid (12,4);
        \draw[-latex] (-0.2,0) -- (13,0) node[right] () {$t {(\sec)}$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-.3) -- (0,4) node[above] {$Q (\times 10^{-5}$ C)};
        \foreach \i in {0,4,...,13}
        \draw[gray!65] (\i,.1)--(\i,-.1) node[below] {$\i$};
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,4}
        \draw[gray!65] (.1,\i)--(-.1,\i) node[left] {$\i$};
        \draw[cyan,line width=3pt,domain=0:13] plot(\x,{3.75*(1-exp(-\x/3))}) ;
        \draw[red,dashed,line width=.5pt] (13,3.75)--(0,3.75) node[left] () {3.75};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The plot is done with this assumptions: *R* = 2.0 MΩ, *C* = 1.5 μF, *V*<sub>0</sub> = 25 V.